# Debian-Server: Incoming SSH/PING/TELNET/... works - outgoing does not

Tags: networking, debian, linux-networking, debian-jessie

I've mentioned a strange behavior of my linux-system:

After rebooting the system I can connect to it via SSH and the server responses to PING. But the server itself can not ping any other servers.

```
# ping google.de
^C
#
```

I also tried pinging 8.8.8.8

```
# ping 8.8.8.8
^C
#
```

I also checked IPTables-Firewall:

```
# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

This is the output of `iptables-save`:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Jan  9 15:32:05 2016
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [195612:29645179]
:INPUT ACCEPT [195139:29597314]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [191509:144973069]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [191487:144962209]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jan  9 15:32:05 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Jan  9 15:32:05 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [16150:972249]
:INPUT ACCEPT [15873:943476]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2778:195347]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2778:195347]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jan  9 15:32:05 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Jan  9 15:32:05 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [82916:15824405]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [76735:21176202]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jan  9 15:32:05 2016
```

This is the traceroute to 8.8.8.8

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  *^C
```

And the routing itself:

```
Kernel-IP-Routentabelle
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         85.xx.1.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.1.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.3.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.6.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.7.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.12.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.14.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.16.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.17.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.18.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.19.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.21.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.22.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.23.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.24.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.25.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.26.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.27.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.28.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.29.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.30.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.xx.31.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.4.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.7.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.9.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.10.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.12.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.13.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.14.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.15.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.19.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.21.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.23.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.24.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.26.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.27.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.28.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.29.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.30.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.31.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.32.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.33.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.34.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.35.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.36.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.37.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.38.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.39.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.40.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.41.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.43.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.44.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.45.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.46.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.48.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.49.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
89.xxx.50.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
1xx.24.208.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
1xx.24.209.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
1xx.24.210.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

This is the result of ip addr show

```
ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:31:49:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 85.xx.x.246/24 brd 85.xx.x.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 85.xx.xx.80/24 brd 85.xx.xx.255 scope global eth0:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 193.xx.xxx.203/24 brd 193.xx.xxx.255 scope global eth0:2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
and so on
```

The interfaces are UP and running - what could possibly cause this problem?

I monitored the connections via `tcpdump`: This is the result:

```
# tcpdump dst 8.8.8.8 -w /tmp/tcpdump
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C70 packets captured
70 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel


listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:21:57.484886 IP server.example.com.36115 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 47207+ A? collector.newrelic.com. (40)
15:21:57.484895 IP server.example.com.36115 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 6559+ AAAA? collector.newrelic.com. (40)
15:21:57.873854 IP server.example.com.59617 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 29097+ PTR? 231.201.203.64.in-addr.arpa. (45)
15:21:57.874880 IP server.example.com > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 23608, seq 99, length 64
15:21:58.119951 IP server.example.com.56377 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 16236+ PTR? 8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa. (38)
15:21:58.396881 IP server.example.com.47984 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 58900+ PTR? 52.39.140.95.in-addr.arpa. (43)
15:21:58.882882 IP server.example.com > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 23608, seq 100, length 64
15:21:59.794301 IP server.example.com.33657 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 49356+ PTR? 194.94.45.70.in-addr.arpa. (43)
15:21:59.964218 IP server.example.com.44113 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 51976+ PTR? 178.186.148.66.in-addr.arpa. (45)
15:22:00.033621 IP server.example.com.51669 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 46383+ A? 110.208.16.216.ix.dnsbl.manitu.net. (52)
15:22:01.096586 IP server.example.com > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1155, seq 1, length 64
15:22:01.272051 IP server.example.com.50628 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 33444+ A? 221.170.189.113.sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org. (54)
15:22:01.639669 IP server.example.com.48543 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 694+ PTR? 242.40.10.176.in-addr.arpa. (44)
15:22:01.918993 IP server.example.com.60321 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 45439+ A? 11.179.189.5.ix.dnsbl.manitu.net. (50)
15:22:02.098337 IP server.example.com > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1155, seq 2, length 64
15:22:02.546164 IP server.example.com.48905 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 4436+ PTR? 231.218.240.187.in-addr.arpa. (46)
15:22:02.878905 IP server.example.com.59617 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 29097+ PTR? 231.201.203.64.in-addr.arpa. (45)
15:22:03.106976 IP server.example.com > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1155, seq 3, length 64
15:22:03.125014 IP server.example.com.56377 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 16236+ PTR? 8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa. (38)
15:22:03.444852 IP server.example.com.39858 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 30888+ A? 52.39.140.95.ix.dnsbl.manitu.net. (50)
15:22:04.114892 IP server.example.com > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1155, seq 4, length 64
15:22:04.799409 IP server.example.com.33657 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 49356+ PTR? 194.94.45.70.in-addr.arpa. (43)
15:22:04.969287 IP server.example.com.44113 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 51976+ PTR? 178.186.148.66.in-addr.arpa. (45)
15:22:05.038655 IP server.example.com.51669 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 46383+ A? 110.208.16.216.ix.dnsbl.manitu.net. (52)
15:22:08.146971 IP server.example.com > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1155, seq 8, length 64
15:22:08.449933 IP server.example.com.39858 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 30888+ A? 52.39.140.95.ix.dnsbl.manitu.net. (50)
15:22:09.154943 IP server.example.com > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1155, seq 9, length 64
15:22:09.714225 IP server.example.com.55765 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 3955+ A? 231.201.203.64.ix.dnsbl.manitu.net. (52)
15:22:10.043790 IP server.example.com.59926 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 7570+ A? 110.208.16.216.sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org. (53)
```

Comment: Does `ping 8.8.8.8` work? Besides: Did you do any research at first on your own? If so, which one? And if so, why don't you describe the steps you've taken so far? If not: Why not?

Comment: Sorry, I was a little bit in panic because the server is running an important service.

I updated my initial question

Comment: And please `route -n && traceroute -n 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Added these information, too

Comment: Which ip do you access your server from? Check if your server is actually accessible from outside with this service: http://ping.eu/port-chk/

Comment: Server is accessible from outside without problems. I can not access ANY IP (only the IPs that are configured on the server itself)

Comment: Whats the purpose of all these route table entries? Besides: To debug your problem, run `tcpdump` or `wireshark` or something similar on your interface to get an idea, what's happening with your packets..

Comment: Could you run `iptables-save` to get a complete picture? Your `iptables -L -n` might not be complete..

Comment: If you got `85.xx.1.1` as your gateway, make sure your have an IP from `85.xx.1.0/24` assigned to your network card `ip addr show`

Comment: The server has a lot of IPs in use, this is the reason for all these route table entries.

I added the result of tcpdump now.

Comment: Added the output of `iptables-save`

Comment: "The server has a lot of IPs in use, this is the reason for all these route table entries."...makes no sense: As all these use the same router (85.xx.1.1), you don't need these.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any problem on your server.  Have you checked your router?  Just because it allows traffic IN to your server, does not necessarily mean it will allow traffic OUT.